# Insert header on second page of a word template, while the second page doesn't exist yet

Tags: vba, ms-word, office365

I need to create a Word-Template, which dynamically adds a logo into the header of a letter. To simplify the user experience, the original template gets generated with only one page.
The process goes like this:

1. The user opens the template via "Document>New" in Word
2. The user can choose between different companies and logos via a UserForm
3. Depending on the choice of company/logo, different content is added to the letter

I do have a constraint, that the footer on the first page is different to the ones from the second page onwards.

This means, that when I add a picture into the header on the first page via VBA code and I add text (or just blank space), the logo doesn't get repeated.

So basically the question I have is, if I can add a picture to a header from the second page onward, while the page doesn't exist yet?

My code at the moment is something like the following, although I have removed the parts for image formating, since it isn't relevant in my opinion:

```
With ActiveDocument
 .Sections(1).Footers(wdHeaderFooterFirstPage) _ 
 .Range.InlineShapes.AddPicture(path)
End With
```

I have also tried to preemptively add the header to the following pages, but it doesn't seem to work

```
With ActiveDocument
 .Sections(1).Footers(wdHeaderFooterFirstPage) _ 
 .Range.InlineShapes.AddPicture(path)
End With

With ActiveDocument
 .Sections(1).Footers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary) _ 
 .Range.InlineShapes.AddPicture(path)
End With
```

Comment: A better way of doing that is to save the different headers as Quick Parts/Building Blocks in the template. You can then use your code to insert the relevant part(s) in the document. You then have a self-contained solution with no dependency on additional files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out, why the image was "moving" to page 2, when I added a second (and third and so on) page. It had to do with the way I was adding the image.

Originally I was defining the anchor, where I attached the image, as `Anchor:=Selection.Range`. I was just using code, which I knew to work with the format of the images.

So I just removed the anchor and now the image gets attached properly in each header, no matter if on page 1 or 2 or 13.

See below, the code, that worked for me.

I did, of course, implement it properly in a function, which I call, when I need it ;-)

```
ActiveDocument.Sections(1).PageSetup.DifferentFirstPageHeaderFooter = True

' Insert image in header for page 1

    With ActiveDocument.Sections(1).Headers(wdHeaderFooterFirstPage)
        With .Shapes.AddPicture(FileName:=filename, LinkToFile:=False, SaveWithDocument:=True)
            .name = "Logo_Page1"
            .Width = CentimetersToPoints(21)
            .Height = CentimetersToPoints(3)
            .RelativeHorizontalPosition = wdRelativeHorizontalPositionPage
            .Left = CentimetersToPoints(0)
            .RelativeVerticalPosition = wdRelativeVerticalPositionPage
            .Top = CentimetersToPoints(0)
            .WrapFormat.Type = wdWrapBehind
        End With
    End With
    
' Insert image in header from page 2 onwards
    
    With ActiveDocument.Sections(1).Headers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary)
        With .Shapes.AddPicture(FileName:=filename, LinkToFile:=False, SaveWithDocument:=True,Anchor:=Selection.Range)
            .name = "Logo_Page2"
            .Width = CentimetersToPoints(21)
            .Height = CentimetersToPoints(3)
            .RelativeHorizontalPosition = wdRelativeHorizontalPositionPage
            .Left = CentimetersToPoints(0)
            .RelativeVerticalPosition = wdRelativeVerticalPositionPage
            .Top = CentimetersToPoints(0)
            .WrapFormat.Type = wdWrapBehind
        End With
    End With
```

Comment: ActiveDocument.Sections(1).Headers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Shapes.AddPicture looks familiar. I'd appreciate an upvote. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I've included two statements to place a picture. Either will work:

```
Sub AddGraphicPage2()
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  Dim aSection As Section
  For Each aSection In ActiveDocument.Sections
    With aSection
      .Headers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Shapes.AddPicture FileName:="C:\picture.png"
      .Headers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range.InlineShapes.AddPicture FileName:="C:\picture.png"
    End With
  Next aSection
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Checking all sections makes this a general-purpose macro that will also work with more complex documents than a single page.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion - I doesn't really solve my problem though. When I implement your solution, it still happens that on the first page the picture is embedded correctly, but when I type and get to the second page, there is no image in the header.

Comment: @MaxAbbe - You need to check your page setup. On the layout tab you should only have "Different first page" checked, in which case the primary header/footer applies to all other pages. If you have "Different odd and even" checked then the primary header/footer only applies to the odd pages, which would explain why there is no image on page 2.

Comment: @TimothyRylatt - Thank you for your help. I checked and the option was unchecked. Although I felt really stupid for a moment, that I may have missed such a basic setting.


I played around some more with calling the functions to insert the image and I have observed some weird behaviour: When I add a lot of text via Copy&Paste, the image doesn't appear on page 1. But if I delete the picture in the header on page 2, there is another picture beneath it. It seems like, the header gets moved one page down for some strange reason. Do you have any idea why?

Comment: @MaxAbbe - not without seeing your full code. It is possible that what you are copying, or where you are pasting, is causing the problem. Personally, I would not base a solution on the use of Copy & Paste.

Comment: Yeah, the usage of Copy&Paste was just to add a lot of text quickly - Think "Lorem Ipsum"-Style.
I did fix my problem, although it was another issue entirely (see my own answer). But thank you anyway for helping!

Comment: @MaxAbbe - you do realise that you can generate lorem ipsum text directly in Word? Just type =lorem(*p*,*l*) and hit return. *p* = number of paragraphs, *l* = number of lines, e.g. =lorem(9,7)